# How to create a local Windows-based service bus outside of Azure, similar to Redis with automatic fail-over?

Tags: redis, signalr, azureservicebus

We are implementing a service/message-bus feature in our [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki) application and have been looking at [Redis](http://redis.io/), with automatic fail-over using [Redis Sentiel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel).  We would like to maintain our own servers and have read [SignalR powered by Service Bus](http://vasters.com/clemensv/2012/02/13/SignalR+Powered+By+Service+Bus.aspx).  Since this is a Winddows Azure implementation, how can I accomplish this in our internal network with VM's with automatic fail-over similar to the Redis solution discussed above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at Service Bus for Windows Server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193022(v=azure.10).aspx

It has API symmetry between Azure Service Bus and the Windows Server API (particularly for messaging: queues and topics/similar to SignalR).  It doesn't include the caching and ACS services. However, if you want the Azure Service Bus - Caching...you can get that in:

AppFabric for Windows Server
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx